# How to pad an image in java?

Tags: java, arrays, image-processing, padding

in order to padding an image, I am trying to pad a small 3*3 array. I could mirror original array's last column and last row to get a 4*4 array (my first code). But when I am trying this code for an 3*4 array I get ArrayIndexOutOfBound error (my second code). Can anyone help please?

-

### My first code:

```
package org.eclipse.wb.swing;

public class Padding_test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int[][] table = new int[3][3];
        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row ++)
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
                table[row][col] = ((row * 3 + col)+1);

        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row ++){
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++){
                System.out.print (table[row][col]);
    }
          System.out.println();  
        }

        System.out.println();

        int [][] temp = new int[table.length+1][table[0].length+1] ;

        for ( int x=0 ; x<table[0].length+1 ; x++){
            for (int y=0 ; y<table.length+1 ; y++){
                temp[x][y] = 0;

                System.out.print(temp[x][y]);
            }
            System.out.println();
            }

        for ( int count = 0 ; count < table.length ; count++){
        for (int xx=0 ; xx<table[0].length ; xx++)
        {
            temp[xx][count]= table[count][xx];
            temp[xx+1][count]= temp[xx][count];
        }

        }

        int th = temp.length;

        System.out.println();

        for (int yy = 0 ; yy< temp.length ; yy++){

            temp [yy][th-1]=temp [yy][th-2];            }


        for (int px =0 ; px<temp.length ; px++){
            for (int py=0 ; py<temp[0].length ; py++){
                System.out.print(temp[py][px]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

_

### My Second code

But I get error  when I run this code :

```
package org.eclipse.wb.swing;

public class Padding_test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

        System.out.println();        
        int [][] table = { {1,2,3,4},{2,5,7,9},{6,8,9,0}};

        for (int i =0 ; i <table.length ; i ++){
            for (int j =0 ; j < table[0].length ; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(table[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println();
        int width = table[0].length;
        int Height = table.length;

        System.out.println( "Width = "+ width );
        System.out.println("Height = " + Height);    

        int [][] temp = new int[table.length+1][table[0].length+1] ;

        for ( int x=0 ; x<table.length+1 ; x++){
            for (int y=0 ; y<table[0].length+1 ; y++){
                temp[x][y] = 0;

                System.out.print(temp[x][y]);
            }
            System.out.println();
            }

        for ( int count = 0 ; count < table.length ; count++){
            for (int xx=0 ; xx<table[0].length ; xx++){
                temp[xx][count]= table[count][xx];
                temp[xx+1][count]= temp[xx][count];
            }       
        }

        int th = temp.length;

        System.out.println();

        for (int yy = 0 ; yy< temp.length ; yy++){                              
            temp [yy][th-1]=temp [yy][th-2];            
        }       

        for (int px =0 ; px<temp.length ; px++){
            for (int py=0 ; py<temp[0].length ; py++){
                System.out.print(temp[py][px]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: At what line do you get your exception? Also, what do you do to make it a 3x4 array?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in this part:

```
for (int x=0 ; x<table[0].length+1 ; x++) {
    for (int y=0 ; y<table.length+1; y++) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

You should switch the places of `table[0].length+1` and `table.length+1`. And preferrably use `x` as index instead of `0` (but it should not matter since it is a matrix).

Result:

```
for (int x=0 ; x<table.length+1 ; x++) {
    for (int y=0 ; y<table[x].length+1; y++) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

In your code you also have `System.out.print(temp[py][px]);` which throws an error. You should change the places of `py` and `px` so it looks like this: `System.out.print(temp[px][py]);`

**Update:** You have a third issue here:

```
for (int count = 0 ; count < table.length; count++){
    for (int xx=0 ; xx < table[0].length; xx++){
        temp[xx][count]= table[count][xx];
        temp[xx+1][count]= temp[xx][count];
    }       
}
```

I don't know what you are trying to do here, but this is bad code:

- If `table.length` is bigger than `table[0].length`, then `temp[xx][count]` will throw an exception.
- If `table[0].length` is bigger than `table.length`, then both `temp[xx][count]` and 
   `temp[xx+1][count]` will throw an exception.

Comment: No, it doesn't make any difference. I still get the same error. I also tried x as an index. No progress though.

Comment: I edited my question. I added both versions of my code. I have no problem on a 3*3 array but when on my second code try to pad a 4*3 array I will get this error :                                                                            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
 at org.eclipse.wb.swing.Padding_test.main(Padding_test.java:45)

Comment: @Nazi Edited to answer you.

Comment: @Nazi Edited again. You had a lot of errors. I think I found the last one now.

Comment: well ,Sorry. it is a bad code because I am a beginner. I will try what you suggest. Thanx though.